# Can .aaf Davinci Resolve (V17) files be imported into Pro Tools

Tags: pro-tools, aaf

I’m trying to import an .aaf audio-only file bundle created using Davinci Resolve (V17) into Avid Pro Tools, and I’ve encountered some problems:

1. The resulting output is unsynchronised with the separate video stream (by several seconds, it seems).
2. Some of the original bundled audio files weren’t transferred at all.

Just for some context, the original file contains 250 frame handles, and the audio is multi-channel.

What might be causing the problem and are there any solutions?